# How to scroll while typing in a NSTextInput field?

Tags: cocoa

I have a `NSTextInput` Field with an attached `NSScrollView`. As I type and hit the character return the view will not scroll and the text types below the visible area of the `NSTextInput` field (not the best user experience).

I've been searching for `NSTextInput` and `NSScrollView` but haven't found anything useful. Also, changing to a `NSTextView` is not really an option as the class is used in other dialogs which I can't tamper with.

I was hoping someone here might have a suggestion on how to scroll the view so the insertion point remains visible?

Comment: There is no such thing as `NSTextEdit` in MacOS, Smorri.  Are you talking about [`NSTextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?  If so, fix your question.  And add a screenshot or code to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was late at night and I was at home instead of work, so my memory failed me =-)

Comment: I won't be back at work until Tuesday, but this point there is not much to take a screen shot of. I attached a NSScrollView to a NSTextImput field in Interface Builder. Afterwards I noticed the view would not scroll as you began to type below the visible rect. Code wise, I couldn't find a solution to try. A co-worker did suggested capturing a test change message and then scrolling to the insertion point each time, but that doesn't seem like the best answer either.